# Batch conversion of Shapefiles to Topojson

Tags: ogr2ogr, batch, topojson

Can i convert more than one shapefile .shp to topojson. Can this be performed using batch processing?

I can convert shape file to topojson one by one but i have about 6000 files and i don't want to merge them i want them to be separately converted to topojson.

I can also batch process ogr2ogr but don't know how to perform that on topojson. Is there any way i could perform this task using a folder of is there any alternate solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple bash script should do the trick. For example, you can paste this into your terminal, assuming you’re in the same directory as your shapefiles:

```
for shapefile in *.shp; do
  topojson -o `basename -s .shp $shapefile`.json -- $shapefile
done
```

Alternatively, you can put this code into a script, `batch.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for shapefile in *.shp; do
  topojson -o `basename -s .shp $shapefile`.json -- $shapefile
done
```

Make the script executable using `chmod u+x batch.sh`, and then run it as `./batch.sh`.

Comment: It worked like this

for /R %f in (*.shp) do topojson -o "%~dpnf.topojson" "%f"

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to read and write the TopoJSON format using `ogr2ogr`:

> Starting with OGR 2.0, the GeoJSON driver can read the TopoJSON format

(Source: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_geojson.html)

Instead, you can use the **topojson** command-line application:
https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki
An example of its application:
http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/06/converting-shapefiles-to-topojson.html

Answer (score 1):

I edited the code and it worked this way.

for /R %f in (*.shp) do topojson -o "%~dpnf.topojson" "%f"

Thanks

The procedure Included

Install Fw tools
Install Node.js
Set proxy in fwtools if required using

npm config set proxy `http://10.x.x.x:port`

Install Python the default path should be c:\python27\python.exe

after that run command set python=%pyhton%;c:\python27\python.exe

Install Visual Studio 2010

npm install -g topojson --python

or if it does not work try

npm install -g topojson --python --msvs_version=2010

If there is some error during installation try installing Install Visual c++ 2005